# Open browser when clicked on fcm notification instead of opening launcher activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I want to send url with FCM to android application. Is it possible to open browser when clicked on FCM notification instead of opening launcher activity? I know it possible with overriding `onMessageReceived()` method but i don't want do it. I checked the `click_action` parameter in payload but as Firebase said:

> If specified, an activity with a matching intent filter is launched
>   when a user clicks on the notification.

I'm try to add `click_action` in CustomData inside firebase cloudMessaging panel like this:

[image]

But it not working and open application instead.

I'm used postman to send notification for this purpose and add `click_action` to `notification` object like this:

[image]

Notification send to my device but when clicked on it, nothing happened!!!

**Important:** My apk released on GooglePlay and i can't change the source code of application.

Anybody help please.

Comment: did you try notification pending  intent

Comment: @Lenoarod No. Apk released on googlePlay and I can't change source code.

Comment: i don't think so it has to be supported first from the code. You can't send something and believe it will open browser. The intent filters for pending intent has to be set.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

when your app is in the background. the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.

if the message has data, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

so you can according to different data, to handle the condition.

1. Set click_action in the notification payload

```
{
  ...
  "notification": {
      "click_action": "activity action"
  },
 ....
}
```

2.in the mainfest you have to config the inter fliter.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="some action" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

then when you click it, it will open that action activity.
here is the document descirbe:

> the If specified, an activity with a matching intent filter is launched when a user clicks on the notification.

so I think you try to set the click_action acton to match the browser chooser action, or "Intent.ACTION_VIEW" and data set like that "http://"

I hope that can give you some help

Comment: Thanks Lenoarod, but i try that and used url in click_action parameter and it don't work.

Comment: set click_action to "ACTION_VIEW" and data is URL is not worked?

Comment: I don't want change current source code. As i said apk released on googlePlay

Comment: I mean you set it in the notification payload.

Comment: @Lenoarod where would you specify url? You said try to use `"click_action": "Intent.ACTION_VIEW"`, but where to set the actual URL? Because if app is in background, and notification has both `Notification` and `Data`, FCM will automatically make notification without call to `onMessageReceived()`. This is what I want, because this way FCM retrieves `image` for me (if you try to get it yourself, some devices will not allow due to battery saver mechanism, which prevent background networking).

Answer (score 0):

Pass Intent of setData in PendingIntent.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(link));

PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
myNotification.setContentIntent(pending);
```